# ValueError at /sendrequest/bandit Cannot assign "'jacob'": "ConnectRequest.sender" must be a "Profile" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am making a friend request feature and i am not able to save my data this error is showing up everytime.
this is my `views.py`

```
def sendrequest(request,receiver):
receiver_user = Profile.objects.get(username=receiver).username
sender=request.user
sender_user=Profile.objects.get(username=sender).username
connection=ConnectRequest(sender=sender_user,
    receiver=receiver_user,
    status="Pending"
)
connection.save()
return redirect("buddylist")
```

this is my `Profile model`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
idno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
email=models.CharField(max_length=40)
username=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

this is my `ConnectRequest model`

```
class ConnectRequest(models.Model):
sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="receiver")
choice=(
    ("Accepted","Accepted"),
    ("Declined","Declined"),
    ("Pending","Pending")
)
status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=choice,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.sender} to {self.receiver} status {self.status}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender_user=Profile.objects.get(username=sender).username`

needs to change to

`sender_user=Profile.objects.get(username=sender.username)`

for starters. `username` needs to be a Charfield, but you were giving it `request.user` which is a User instance.

And you need to change

`receiver_user = Profile.objects.get(username=receiver).username`

to

`receiver_user = Profile.objects.get(username=receiver)`

because when you're passing it to ConnectRequest, it expects a Profile instance and you were giving it a username

Comment: Most importantly, I've seen you make this error twice recently. Be sure that when you're doing a `.create()` on a Django model, that you're giving it the right types of objects.

Comment: can you please recommend a way to avoid duplicate request

Comment: instead of a `ConnectRequest.objects.create()` look up Djangos documentation on `.get_or_create()`. It will only create a new object if one doesn't exist with the exact parameters you gave it. If one already exists, it just does a `.get()` on it.